# Expose javascript errors in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, error-handling

in some cases, the angular engine doesn't output the raw **javascript** error. For example

```js
myapp.directive('helloWorld', function() {
return {
    scope: '@',
    restrict: 'AE',
    template: '<p ng-click="clearMessage2()">Hello, World! {{message}}</p>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
       scope.clearMessage = function() {
          scope.message = '';
       }
   }
}});
```

When I click on **p** element produced with directive I'm expecting the error in console to say **clearMessage2()** is not defined, but this doesn't happen and the only way to check things is to use console.log inside clearMessage definition.

Is it possible to change that behavior of angular.js and do not hide errors happening inside JS code?

Comment: No - angular swallows errors from `undefined` function by substituting them with `angular.noop`

Answer (score 4):

It is possible, but not recommended. The problem is that angular does not execute the method in the ng-click directive as is (like in regular onclick), but instead evaluates expressions using the **$parse** service. From the angular doc:

> Angular does not use JavaScript's eval() to evaluate expressions.
>   Instead Angular's $parse service processes these expressions.

The implementation of expression evaluation in Angular is deliberately forgiving.

> In JavaScript, trying to evaluate undefined properties generates ReferenceError or TypeError. In Angular, expression evaluation is forgiving to undefined and null. It makes more sense to show nothing than to throw an exception if a is undefined (perhaps we are waiting for the server response, and it will become defined soon). If expression evaluation wasn't forgiving we'd have to write bindings that clutter the code

So the $parseProvider will not execute an undefined function at all, instead it will execute a **noop** function (which is an implementation of a null object pattern). Here is an excerpt from the **$parseFunctionCall** method:

```
var fn = fnGetter(scope, locals, context) || noop;
```

The execution of a null object will do nothing, and that is what's happening. You could probably achieve what you want by modifying the $parseFunctionCall to execute any function, instead of executing a noop function.

Changing code looks like the only option since configuration of these services is not sufficient for your use-case. However, i don't think it's a recommended approach unless you know the Angular API very well.

For additional reading:

[Angular expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

[$parse service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse)

Comment: What if an expression is used, like so: `ng-click="foo = 4"`? This solution falls flat

Comment: also, presumably, the OP was interested in a broader solution of function expression invocation than `ng-click`

Comment: yes, I was interested in broad solution to avoid Angular intercept and hide any js error. I'd rather get normal exception with the link to file where it happened instead of swallowing it quietly

Comment: @DmitrySemenov, why is this of concern?

Comment: You are both right. My initial answer was flawed and not covering all scenarios. Rewritten answer.

Comment: @TheZenCoder, so the answer is that there is no answer short of forking Angular?

Comment: @New Dev based on my short research it looks like that. Do you know an easier approach?

Comment: @TheZenCoder, no, I don't think there is... as my comment to the OP suggested

Comment: I have seen there are some configuration options in the $parseProvider, but nothing even close to disabling the 'forgiving' mode.