# Debugging: ng-click and non-existent functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Before fixing the problem I had an element (inside an HTML template) with a ng-click which was calling an non-existent function.

Is there a way to enable a strict mode (like use strict in JS) or something similar to see this kind of problems in the console?

UPDATE: I tried also with $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(true) without success

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155171/expose-javascript-errors-in-angular-js

Comment: Can you Add the source code ?

Comment: @Kristján: nice link. I think that there isn't a way to catch these errors without modifying angular.js...

Comment: Can you have a look here http://excellencenodejsblog.com/angularjs-compile-parse-interpolate/ ? You can manually call compiler functions compile, parse and interpolate. These may help if you can modify code you debug. They have to be applied expression by exprssion, and cannot be set on in one place like strict mode.

Comment: @mico: that link is not what I'm looking for. Manually checking every expression of a project is not feasible for me

Comment: based on the linked answer by @Kristján and if you have the ability to modify angularjs, you could have it send something to the console.log anytime there is a noop.  Not ideal but perhaps a place to start.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short Answer:** There is no option to do this in vanilla AngularJS, however it can be done with a hack.

**Long Answer:** The expressions you use in DOM event handling directives (such as ng-click, ng-keydown, and ng-submit) are compiled by Angular's [$parse](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/docs/api/ng/service/$parse) service. You can see where this happens inside the [code for the event directive](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.8/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js#L60). The $parse service includes its own implementation of a lexer and parser, which compile the expression down into JavaScript.

The generated JavaScript has a bunch of safety checks to prevent things from happening, such as errors being thrown from use of undefined functions. A button with this code:

```
<button ng-click="handleClick()">Click Me!<button>
```

Will end up generating JavaScript for the event handler that does something similar to this:

```
if ($scope.handleClick != null) {
    return $scope.handleClick();
} else {
    return undefined;
}
```